# Define Feature Macro: Compiler Argument vs Source Code?

Tags: c, macros

I recently came across the feature macro `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` which allows to specify the minimum required POSIX version when including headers that contain POSIX functions like [`strdup`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/functions/strdup.html) (`<string.h>`, Also upcoming to C23) or [`clock_gettime`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/clock_gettime%60) (`<time.h>`) for example. The correctly way to enable `strdup` would be to define `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` at least `200401L` (Year 2004, version 1), for `clock_gettime` it would be at least `200101L`. Some library vendors might not write checks/`#ifs` to enable or disable the function declarations, which would make some programs not compile with other library implementations, when the programmer did not define the feature macro.

---

There are two ways you could possibly enable the POSIX features.

#### 1. Define before inclusion

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200401L
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
```

#### 2. Define in the compiler arguments and ensure it in the source:

```
gcc ... -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200401L
```

in a source file

```
#if !defined _POSIX_C_SOURCE || _POSIX_C_SOURCE < 200401L
#  error the minimum required POSIX version is 2004.1
#endif
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
```

I thought about inserting the check, because a source file might be compiled in a different way (Other compiler, other buildchain, other makefile etc...), this prevents from missing the compiler argument.

---

I think the first is the quickest, but the second is more clean.

#### Questions

1. Does the first have a problem if a header was included before the feature macro was defined? (See code below)
2. Are previously disabled functions enabled because the file is now included with a version number (greater than the default)?
3. Is there a better way to define and ensure these macros?

```
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
...
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200401L
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
```

Comment: Header files typically use guard macros so that the bulk of the header file is conditionally compiled only once per compilation unit. Therefore, the feature macro needs to be defined before the first inclusion of the header file.

Comment: I think the first way, directly in the source, is the more appropriate.

Comment: I'm not sure if it is a better way, but one option is to define the feature test macros in a header file and include that first in the .c files.

Answer (score 1):

These defines definitely belong in the source code as they state a requirement of your code. If your code needs a feature macro, you're basically saying it requires (some) of the functions the macro will enable. If you do not put that into your source file, how are you going to document it?

And do not try to do something fancy as in your example where you re-include some headers. That definitely does not work in almost all cases.

Defining the feature macro from the compiler command line is not recommended. Those should only be used to pass compile time info to your code that isn't know at the time the code is written. eg. a version number or to enable/disable optional behaviour of your code.

Comment: In the same way you could reason to define/change the language standard in the source code itself, which is ridiculos. Adding the `-D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=...` would have similar meaning to the `-std=...` option, just changing the standard version of a library instead of the language. When writing header only libraries, requiring a minimal version of the POSIX standard with the described `#if-#error` construct is the only option hou have. You wouldn't expect to change the value of `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` to change inside a header.